# C#_How to SUMMARY a format number string

Tags: c#, regex

How to SUMMARY a format number string  :
String input:

```
Car2Bike4Ship3Bike6Car9Ship8Car7Car2
```

This is my out put string :

```
Car : 2+9+7+2
Bike : 4+6
Ship : 3+8
```

My code:

```
String source = “Car2Bike4Ship3Bike6Car9Ship8Car7Car2”;
        var result = Regex
.Matches(source, @"(?<name>[A-z_[ạảàáãăắẳằặẵâấẩầậẫóỏòọõôốổồộỗơớởờợỡéèẻẹẽêếềểệễúùủụũưứừửựữíìỉịĩýỳỷỵỹđ_ẠẢÀÁÃĂẮẲẰẶẴÂẤẨẦẬẪÓỎÒỌÕÔỐỔỒỘỖƠỚỞỜỢỠÉÈẺẸẼÊẾỀỂỆỄÚÙỦỤŨƯỨỪỬỰỮÍÌỈỊĨÝỲỶỴỸĐ_a-z]+)(?<size>([0-9]+\.[0-9])|([0-9]+))")
.OfType<Match>()
.Select(match => new
{
    name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
    size = double.Parse(match.Groups["size"].Value),
})

.GroupBy(value => value.name)
.Select(chunk => String.Format("{0}: {1}",
   chunk.Key, String.Join(" + ", chunk.Select(item => item.size))));
        String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
               report = report.Replace(": 0", ":");
               report = report.Replace(": +", ":");
               txbkqvl.Text = Convert.ToString(report);
```

Now, I want a SUMARY ahead at those lines and a special item “CAR” treated . Look like:

```
11 Car :
2 Unit(s) 2
1 Unit(s) 9
1 Unit(s) 7 
10 Bike : 4+6
11 Ship : 3+8
```

I am not sure that my code is trending.
Thank a lot!!!

Comment: To match a letter, use `\p{L}` in C# regex. No need for spelled out ranges.

Comment: Thanks. my language contain Unicode character. this just a ex the same my case. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the sum should be quite easy, something like

```
.Select(chunk => String.Format("{0} {1}: {2}",
   chunk.Sum(item => item.size), chunk.Key, String.Join(" + ", chunk.Select(item => item.size))));
```

As for the special treatment... And honestly the whole thing in general, I would suggest breaking the code into easy-to-read steps and working from there. Your kind of "guru code" is very compact, but difficult to understand and modify.

First parse the data into simple objects, then process those objects however you want in as many steps as it takes. Doing everything in one huge LINQ chain is not always the best practice.